# Highlight specific words in a sentence with diacritrics

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I am searching for some improvements, particularly in the regex, in the way I highlight specific words in a string.

- I have keywords into my database stored without any diacritrics
- The user comes with a string with diacritrics
- I find the matches between the keywords and my string modified so that it does not contain any diacritrics
- I highlight the matched words in the original sentence with diacritrics

---

```
 var defaultDiacriticsRemovalap = [
        {'base':'A', 'letters':'\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F'},
        {'base':'AA','letters':'\uA732'},
        {'base':'AE','letters':'\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2'},
        {'base':'AO','letters':'\uA734'},
        {'base':'AU','letters':'\uA736'},
        {'base':'AV','letters':'\uA738\uA73A'},
        {'base':'AY','letters':'\uA73C'},
        {'base':'B', 'letters':'\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181'},
        {'base':'C', 'letters':'\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E'},
        {'base':'D', 'letters':'\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779'},
        {'base':'DZ','letters':'\u01F1\u01C4'},
        {'base':'Dz','letters':'\u01F2\u01C5'},
        {'base':'E', 'letters':'\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E'},
        {'base':'F', 'letters':'\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B'},
        {'base':'G', 'letters':'\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E'},
        {'base':'H', 'letters':'\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D'},
        {'base':'I', 'letters':'\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197'},
        {'base':'J', 'letters':'\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248'},
        {'base':'K', 'letters':'\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2'},
        {'base':'L', 'letters':'\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780'},
        {'base':'LJ','letters':'\u01C7'},
        {'base':'Lj','letters':'\u01C8'},
        {'base':'M', 'letters':'\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C'},
        {'base':'N', 'letters':'\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4'},
        {'base':'NJ','letters':'\u01CA'},
        {'base':'Nj','letters':'\u01CB'},
        {'base':'O', 'letters':'\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C'},
        {'base':'OI','letters':'\u01A2'},
        {'base':'OO','letters':'\uA74E'},
        {'base':'OU','letters':'\u0222'},
        {'base':'OE','letters':'\u008C\u0152'},
        {'base':'oe','letters':'\u009C\u0153'},
        {'base':'P', 'letters':'\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754'},
        {'base':'Q', 'letters':'\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A'},
        {'base':'R', 'letters':'\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782'},
        {'base':'S', 'letters':'\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784'},
        {'base':'T', 'letters':'\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786'},
        {'base':'TZ','letters':'\uA728'},
        {'base':'U', 'letters':'\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244'},
        {'base':'V', 'letters':'\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245'},
        {'base':'VY','letters':'\uA760'},
        {'base':'W', 'letters':'\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72'},
        {'base':'X', 'letters':'\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C'},
        {'base':'Y', 'letters':'\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE'},
        {'base':'Z', 'letters':'\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762'},
        {'base':'a', 'letters':'\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250'},
        {'base':'aa','letters':'\uA733'},
        {'base':'ae','letters':'\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3'},
        {'base':'ao','letters':'\uA735'},
        {'base':'au','letters':'\uA737'},
        {'base':'av','letters':'\uA739\uA73B'},
        {'base':'ay','letters':'\uA73D'},
        {'base':'b', 'letters':'\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253'},
        {'base':'c', 'letters':'\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184'},
        {'base':'d', 'letters':'\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A'},
        {'base':'dz','letters':'\u01F3\u01C6'},
        {'base':'e', 'letters':'\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD'},
        {'base':'f', 'letters':'\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C'},
        {'base':'g', 'letters':'\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F'},
        {'base':'h', 'letters':'\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265'},
        {'base':'hv','letters':'\u0195'},
        {'base':'i', 'letters':'\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131'},
        {'base':'j', 'letters':'\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249'},
        {'base':'k', 'letters':'\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3'},
        {'base':'l', 'letters':'\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747'},
        {'base':'lj','letters':'\u01C9'},
        {'base':'m', 'letters':'\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F'},
        {'base':'n', 'letters':'\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5'},
        {'base':'nj','letters':'\u01CC'},
        {'base':'o', 'letters':'\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275'},
        {'base':'oi','letters':'\u01A3'},
        {'base':'ou','letters':'\u0223'},
        {'base':'oo','letters':'\uA74F'},
        {'base':'p','letters':'\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755'},
        {'base':'q','letters':'\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759'},
        {'base':'r','letters':'\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783'},
        {'base':'s','letters':'\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B'},
        {'base':'t','letters':'\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787'},
        {'base':'tz','letters':'\uA729'},
        {'base':'u','letters': '\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289'},
        {'base':'v','letters':'\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C'},
        {'base':'vy','letters':'\uA761'},
        {'base':'w','letters':'\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73'},
        {'base':'x','letters':'\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D'},
        {'base':'y','letters':'\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF'},
        {'base':'z','letters':'\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763'}
    ];

    var diacriticsMap = {};
    for (var i=0; i < defaultDiacriticsRemovalap.length; i++){
        var letters = defaultDiacriticsRemovalap[i].letters;
        for (var j=0; j < letters.length ; j++){
            diacriticsMap[letters[j]] = defaultDiacriticsRemovalap[i].base;
        }
    }

    // "what?" version ... http://jsperf.com/diacritics/12
    function removeDiacritics (str) {
        return str.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, function(a){ 
           return diacriticsMap[a] || a; 
        });
    }

//Function to highlight matched keywords :
var sentence = "J'eusse été amélioré sans des aigÜs si hauts améliorés et raisonnable. Amélioration réaméliorée";
var output = sentence;
var word = ['eusse','ameliore','aigu','aimerais']; //Matched keywords extracted from database where there are stored without diatrics

var new_s = sentence, match, output, nb = 0, index = [];
var new_s_cache = removeDiacritics(sentence).replace("'"," ");
output = output + "<br />" + new_s_cache ;

for (var i=0;i<word.length;i++){// For each matched word it stores its position and length in index
  var wordInput = word[i].substr(0,4);
  var re = new RegExp("(?:^|\\W)"+wordInput+"(\\w*)(?!\\w)","gi");
  while (match = re.exec(new_s_cache)) {
    index.push([match.index,match[0].length]);
  }
}
index.sort(); // Sort index so that it highlights word in the right order
for (var j=0;j<index.length;j++) { //It hightlights the word in the orginal sentence with diatrics
    new_s = new_s.substr(0,index[j][0]+1+nb) + "<b>" + new_s.substr(index[j][0]+1+nb,index[j][1]) + "</b>" + new_s.substr(index[j][0]+index[j][1]+1+nb);
    nb = nb + 7; // take into account the "<b></b>" length
}

output = output + "<br />" + new_s ;

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = output;
```

Where I am seeking improvements:

- The regex: I want to catch the similar words to keywords. That's why I took arbitrary the 4 first letters and then run a regex to find the words that contains this 4 letters but it's not optimal. Indeed for instance I'd like to find 'unapproved' when the keyword is 'approve'.
- The idea of the code: the juggle between the original sentence and the one without diacritrics appears to be quite fragile.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqabomsg/3/)

Comment: Is the normalization of the text to diacritic-free form important to you, or is it merely an intermediate step towards the goal of finding the search terms?

Comment: Could you explain why "Amélioration" is highlighted in your example, when the search term is "ameliore"? Is word stemming part of the exercise, or is that a bug?

Comment: @200_success Yes the normalization is important to catch words like "côté" which can be badly written "coté" for instance. And secondly yes the word stemming is a part of the exercise : for instance I want to be able to catch amélioration amélioré and reamélioré with the same keyword amélioré reduced here to its four first letters 'amel'

Comment: Please clarify the correct stemming behaviour. In your example, "ameliore" matches "Amélioration" (which I don't expect to match), and fails to match "réaméliorée" (which I do expect to match).

Comment: All right, that is a part of improvements I am searching for. I would like to be able to catch any word similar to keywords (which could be anything with at least four letters but not a stop word). And 'similar' is to define. Here I am telling that all the words with the same four first letters as the keywords' are similar. I know it is not perfect and I think that the regex could be improve so that it catches the xx+fourFirstLetterOf(keywords) words for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid messing around with string indexes if you don't try to normalize the text.  Rather, you can transform the search terms into diacritic-insensitive regular expressions.  For example, `"eusse"` could become `/(?:e|é|É|è|È|ë|Ë)(?:u|ü|Ü)ss(?:e|é|É|è|È|ë|Ë)/`.  You can then apply that regular expression on the text directly.

```js
function normalizedRegExpMaker(normalizationMap) {
    // From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
    function escapeRegExp(str) {
        return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
    }

    // Invert the map, so that the values become keys, and the keys are listed
    // as values.
    var diacriticReverse = (function(equivs) {
        var reverse = {};
        for (c in equivs) {
            if (!reverse[equivs[c]]) {
                reverse[equivs[c]] = [equivs[c]];
            }
            reverse[equivs[c]].push(c);
        }
        return reverse;
    })(normalizationMap);

    var diacriticReverseRe = new RegExp(
        '(?:' + Object.keys(diacriticReverse).join('|') + ')',
        'g'
    );

    return function(s) {
        return escapeRegExp(s).replace(diacriticReverseRe, function(c) {
            return '(?:' + diacriticReverse[c].join('|') + ')';
        });
    };
}

function normalizedWordReplace(normalizationMap, words, text, transform) {
    var lettersRe = '[\\w' + Object.keys(normalizationMap).join('') + ']*';
    var regexpMaker = normalizedRegExpMaker(normalizationMap);
    var re = new RegExp(
        lettersRe + '(?:' + words.map(regexpMaker).join('|') + ')' + lettersRe,
        'gi'
    );

    return text.replace(re, transform);
}

function bolden(s) {
    return '<b>' + s + '</b>';
}

var FRENCH_NORMALIZATION = {
    'ç': 'c',      'Ç': 'c',
    'à': 'a',      'À': 'a',
    'é': 'e',      'É': 'e',
    'è': 'e',      'È': 'e',
    'ë': 'e',      'Ë': 'e',
    'æ': 'ae',     'Æ': 'ae',
    'œ': 'oe',     'Œ': 'oe',
    'ü': 'u',      'Ü': 'u',
};

function search() {
    var searchTerms = $('#terms').val().split(/\s+/);
    var text = $('#text').val();
    var output = normalizedWordReplace(FRENCH_NORMALIZATION, searchTerms, text, bolden);
    $('#output').html(output);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>Search terms (space-separated):<br>
    <input id="terms" size="80"
           value="eusse ameliore aigu aimerais">
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>Text:<br>
    <input id="text" size="80"
           value="J'eusse été amélioré sans des aigÜs si hauts améliorés et raisonnable. Amélioration réaméliorée">
  </label>
  <br>
  <button onclick="search()">Search</button>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Note that in this demo, as in yours, I am playing fast and loose with HTML escaping.  If the text contains, say, a `<script>` tag, it will be injected into the resulting display.

You appear to have used an all-purpose normalization map.  Note that there are likely language-specific rules.  French treats diacritics as mere decorations.  However, that isn't the case in German, where 'ü' is the common way of writing "ue".

Comment: What a brilliant idea! And really fast answer! I reassure you : Nope the text will not contain html tags. And yes, I'll have to be careful about the used language indeed, I had not seen that point. I'll run all that tomorrow but before, could you describe what you're doing when you're typing "var lettersRe = '[\\w' + Object.keys(normalizationMap).join('') + ']*';" please?

Comment: I'd like a regex that includes all letters. Unfortunately, `/\w/` in JavaScript is equivalent to `/[A-Za-z0-9_]/`, which covers just the plain Roman letters. Therefore, I have to supplement it with the recognized diacritic-decorated characters (which are the keys of `normalizationMap`).

Comment: Wow I'm listening new concepts everyday, diacriticReverse